Flutter TextField: how to lose focus on tap outside?
Flutter TextField: how to lose focus on tap outside?
TextField()

It loses focus only when tap another widget that can take focus such as TextField.
What if the TextField is the only one widget in the page?

Read this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onTapOutside.html

In TextField Widget class there is an argument called as onTapOutside, this method will call when-ever you tap outside the TextField, so you can do your code to un-focus or loose focus.
For example:
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTextField({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      // this method will call when you tap outside the TextField
      onTapOutside: (event) {
        // code to unfocus after tap outside
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      },
    );
  }
}


could not regain the focus when tapping the textField.

onTapOutside's default-null behavior already does an unfocus.

wrap your Scaffold with GestureDetector
and when ontap unfocus
like this
 GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        // your scaffold code here
      ),
    )


You can use this code to unfocus keyboard
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
      },
      child: Scaffold()
      },

